# On change load HTML through AJAX with DIV ID filter

Tags: jquery, ajax

1. Onload it have to load with first option value.
2. Have to load HTML inside the AJAX container when value change.
3. While loading through ajax, it have to pull only from "ajax-container" div id. have to do this filter.

Please check below HTML and JS created and working on.

**HTML**

```
 <select id="testElement">
 <option value="test1.html">Test1</option>
 <option value="test2.html">Test2</option>
 </select>

 <div id="container">
 </div>
```

**test1.html**

```
 <div id="ajax-container">
      <section>
           <div>Test 1234</div>
      </section>
 </div>

 <div id="other-container">
 <section>
           <div>Test 4567</div>
      </section>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 //On page load.. load with first option value "test1.html"
 $('#container').load($('#testElement option:first-child').val());

 //on option change, load htmls based on the value inside the AJAX container.
 $('#testElement').on('change', function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          data: {valueType: value, html: encodeURIComponent($('#container').html(data))},
       });
 });
```

Comment: what is this line means `data: {valueType: value, html: encodeURIComponent($('#container').html(data))}`

Comment: Hi.. some one provided this method as a solution for ajax loading.. but its not working.. not sure is there any other way to solve my problem.

Comment: i don't even understand your purpose...you want ajax do what?

Comment: This line data: {valueType: value, html: encodeURIComponent($('#container').html(data))} is the data that will be passed to your back-end code (PHP for example). But here your purpose is a lil bit confusing. Are u loading the value from database or U just wanna show the selected value inside another div.

Comment: Sorry then.. wrong coding used.. Just i need to load the test1.html using ajax (but have to load only "ajax-container" contents. Not "other-container").. thats it.. nothing complicated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, then you can use the following jQuery code instead of your existing code:

```
// change event handler
$("#testElement").on("change", function(e) {
    var ajaxURL = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        success: function(data) {
            var htmlData = $(data);
            $("#container").html(htmlData.filter("#ajax-container").get(0).outerHTML);
        }
    });
});

// use the same handler on page load to load first element data
$("#testElement").trigger("change");
```

This will only work if you have test1.html and test2.html at same level as the main page.

Comment: Hi Vishal.. Thanks.. almost done.. only filtering out "ajax-container" not working. when i use $('#specials--container').html(data); it works fine by loading all the contents inside test1.html

Comment: Ok, let me check again

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: After add your script on our CMS version.. getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined".. HTML we are calling was subpages.

Comment: This can only happen if there is no element with ID `#ajax-container`

Comment: Ajax container was available.. It works fine in HTML version.. when we implement in CMS.. getting below error

Comment: Thanks boss.. will check from my side